# Word to describe a sarcastic, condescending tone/remark

Tags: single-word-requests, connotation, tone

I'm struggling to find the most appropriate word to describe the following type of remark (italicized), or the tone behind it:

> "I wish I could talk to him right now..."
>
> *"There's this great thing called a telephone that allows you to talk to people, even if they're not in the same room. You should try it."*

I looked at synonyms for "sarcastic" and "condescending" I found in the [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english-thesaurus/condescending), Roget's and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/condescending) thesauruses, but didn't see a word that implied both sarcasm/indirectness *and* condescension.
Is there a specific term for this type of remark/tone?

Comment: Anything wrong with *condescending* - it seems to fit quite well to me.

Comment: Well, *condescending* is a bit long, and some people might not understand it. But that's also part of its charm.

Comment: Did you consult a thesaurus??

Comment: @HotLicks Can’t tell if this comment is meant to be a subtle joke... if not, yes, I did. The synonyms in the three thesauri I consulted did not provide the nuance I was looking for. For instance, the neither the entries for “condescending” nor the entries for “sarcastic” provided “snide” or “snarky” as synonyms.

Comment: You should identify the resources you referenced and briefly explain why they did not provide the info you need.  For instance, why did none of arrogant, patronizing, snooty, complaisant, disdainful,  egotistic la-dee-da, lofty, snobbish,  snotty,  supercilious, superior, uppish, or uppity meet your needs?

Comment: I’ll update the question with links later today, and a change in the wording to better convey that I was looking for a word that implied indirectness. I likely couldn’t figure out how to articulate that at the time I asked the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I submit **snide**.

> derogatory or mocking in an indirect way.

Comment: I never knew exactly what a "snide remark" was until now. Thank you!

Comment: I think the remark is too directly condescending to be regarded as *snide*. The latter seems to me to suggest a partly hidden, or underhand insult, where the sting is delayed.

Comment: @WS2 I wouldn't say it's directly condescending as such. Taken literally it's helpful advice. The fact that the statement is meant to be condescending via being completely obvious doesn't make it direct condescension, but that is of course just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps "caustic," which means "[sarcastic in a scathing and bitter way](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20obnoxious&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=define%20caustic)."

Answer (score 1):

A common word these days is [snarky](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snarky).

> sarcastic, impertinent, or irreverent in tone or manner

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of tone, such a comment sounds like **condescending sarcasm**, as mentioned in one of the comments.

> - [**condescending**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/condescending) - If you say that someone is condescending, you are showing your disapproval of the fact that they talk or behave in a way which shows that they think they are superior to other people.

Examples of condescending sarcasm:

> - Oh, congratulations. You've pressed the elevator button twice after it's been pressed. I'm sure it will hurry down now.
> - Oh, thank you. It sounds like a very good idea. In fact, my five-year-old son is always suggesting we try it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be called **patronizing**

Patronizing - [treat with an apparent kindness that betrays a feeling of superiority](https://www.google.com/search?q=patronizing&biw=1280&bih=913&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje19ytk7LLAhUG2yYKHQS7ACkQ_AUIBigA&dpr=1)

Answer (score 0):

I submit **belligerent**

Merriam Webster

> 1 : inclined to or exhibiting assertiveness, hostility, or combativeness

I don't care so much the Webster def, but the Synonyms listed offer a more accurate assessment based on your question IMHO.....

> **Synonyms**
>   aggressive, agonistic, argumentative, assaultive, bellicose, brawly, chippy, combative, confrontational, contentious, discordant, disputatious, feisty, gladiatorial, militant, pugnacious, quarrelsome, scrappy, truculent, warlike

Answer (score -1):

How about *sardonic*? From the definition at [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sardonic):

> **sardonic** *adjective* **1.** characterized by bitter or scornful derision; mocking; cynical; sneering

Comment: I added a citation and link to the language that you quoted as the definition of sardonic, and I formatted it as a block quote. I'm pretty sure that the reason this answer received a downvote is that you did none of those things before submitting it. In future answers at the site, please provide citations (and links, if possible) to language that you are quoting from elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: mmm I see, the things a person learns...